# Password retrieving but "call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" shows

Tags: php

I having a hard time finding how to solve this error:

> Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   F:\Server\xampplite\htdocs\verif.php on line 6

Whenever I try to compile the script, this error comes up.
I'm clueless on where to insert the database connection.
Here's the script:

```
$username = 'Admin';
$password = 'password';

$sth = $dbh->prepare('
  SELECT
    hash
  FROM users
  WHERE
    username = :username
  LIMIT 1
  ');

$sth->bindParam(':username', $username);

$sth->execute();

$user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// Hashing the password with its hash as the salt returns the same hash
if ( crypt($password, $user->hash) == $user->hash ) {
  // Ok!
}
```

Comment: what does  $dbh->prepare() do? how is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dbh` is never initialized in the code you pasted.

You can do it this way, assuming you are using a `mysql` database, the name of your database is `testdb`, and your database is hosted on the same server as your application (hosted on `127.0.0.1`):

```php
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

?>
```

More information in [the documentation](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: Even if my question wasn't clear enough, your answer perfectly worked. I'm new to all this PHP and PDO thing. Your help is really appreciated!